# CSS/JS Top and Left are warped when placing images on top of one another

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got an image of a basketball court and would like to place either a green or red dot on the court (green if a shot was made from that spot, red if missed).

The basketball shots are recorded by someone clicking the image of the court, and then the coordinates (represented as percentages) are saved to the database. After we are done recording, on a separate view, I am calling all of those coordinates and setting the following parameters for them:

```
var marker = document.createElement("IMG");
marker.src = image;
marker.style.width = '4%';
marker.style.position = 'absolute';
marker.style.left = offsetLeft + "%";
marker.style.top = offsetTop + "%";
shotChartBox.appendChild(marker);
```

offetLeft and Top are both just the values from the DB multiplied by 100 and given a % sign.

However, when I do this, the dots always end up just a bit off. If someone clicks in the dead center of the court image, the dot will appear just a bit above and to the right. I know that this is not a data capture problem, because when I went into the browser inspect tool and manually set a dot to have top and left values of exactly 50%, the same thing happened.

I have tried accounting for the 4% width of the dots themselves, but have not been able to find a way to do that and make it work on all browser sizes. As I resize the browser after adding or subtracting 2% here and there, it always throws things off even worse.

Let me know if you have any ideas. I feel as though there is either a positioning or JS thing that I am just not aware of.

```js
//A couple example function calls
displayMarker(0.5, 0.5, "https://i.postimg.cc/8CLJ8Wj6/makeIcon.png");
displayMarker(0.25, 0.25, "https://i.postimg.cc/mDRcTDH6/missIcon.png");

function displayMarker(x, y, image) {
  var courtImage = document.getElementById('shotChart');
  var shotChartBox = document.getElementById('shotChartBox');

  var offsetLeft = x * 100;
  var offsetTop = y * 100;

  var marker = document.createElement("IMG");
  marker.src = image;
  marker.style.width = '4%';
  marker.style.position = 'absolute';
  marker.style.left = offsetLeft + "%";
  marker.style.top = offsetTop + "%";
  shotChartBox.appendChild(marker);
}
```

```html
<h2>Shot Chart</h2>
<div id="shotChartBox">
  <img id="shotChart" src="https://i.postimg.cc/rswKtPg1/shot-Chart.png" width="100%" />
</div>
```

[JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/o8Lr9cgy/).

Comment: Can you post enough of your code - along with resources where necessary - so that we can reproduce the problem you describe? Ideally as a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do), but as code at the very least. I can see some minimal JavaScript, but there's no HTML with any `<img>`, there's no data to show what you're working with, or CSS to show what might be affecting the positioning.

Comment: Working to get that done.

Comment: Done. I've got to learn how to do stack snippets but for now I made a JSFiddle

Comment: When on that JSFiddle, try resizing the browser. To me the spacing that happens is very confusing

Comment: So basically it isn't responsive.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming 0.5, 0.5 is equivalent to the center of the court here is a working solution.

```html
<html>
<style></style>

<body>
  <div id="shotChartBox" style="position: relative;">
    <img style="position: relative" src="https://i.postimg.cc/rswKtPg1/shot-Chart.png" width="100%" height="auto" />
  </div>
  <script>
    displayMarker(0.5, 0.5, "https://i.postimg.cc/8CLJ8Wj6/makeIcon.png");
    displayMarker(0.25, 0.25, "https://i.postimg.cc/mDRcTDH6/missIcon.png");

    function displayMarker(x, y, image) {
      var shotChartBox = document.getElementById("shotChartBox");

      var offsetLeft = x * 100 - 2;
      var offsetTop = y * 100 - 1;

      var marker = document.createElement("IMG");
      marker.src = image;
      marker.style.width = "4%";
      marker.style.position = "absolute";
      marker.style.left = offsetLeft + "%";
      marker.style.top = offsetTop + "%";
      shotChartBox.appendChild(marker);
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```